# SharePoint Discussion Board Flat View

Tags: sharepoint-server, discussion-board

I am currently developing a page where I need to include a discussion board Flat view. I could provide the root folder and content type ID to access the page. Is t possible to add the flat view to other page?

Because when I tried to edit the page where a Flat view exists, I could see the flat view as a web part (It has web part property, etc.).